# What is stomp.py on_before_message method used for?

Tags: stomp

I am using the Class - `PrintingListener` from [stomp.py](https://pypi.org/project/stomp.py/), and it has the method: [`on_before_message`](https://stomppy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stomp.html#stomp.listener.ConnectionListener.on_before_message).

I am not sure why this method is called. I cannot understand the definition. Could someone clarify the use of this method and when it is called?

Comment: The docs literally state `Returns a tuple containing the headers and body (so that implementing listeners can pre-process the content)`

Comment: @DTul what do you mean by it? Could you brief it please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [stomp.py documentation](https://jasonrbriggs.github.io/stomp.py/api.html), the `PrintingListener` "just prints all interactions between the client and server." The `on_before_message` is one of the methods defined by stomp.py therefore the `PrintingListener` invokes it.

[The stomp.py API documentation](http://jasonrbriggs.github.io/stomp.py/stomp.html?highlight=on_before_message#stomp.listener.ConnectionListener.on_before_message) says this about `on_before_message`:

> Called by the STOMP connection before a message is returned to the client app. Returns a tuple containing the headers and body (so that implementing listeners can pre-process the content).
>
> **Parameters**:
>
> - **headers** (*dict*) – the message headers
> - **body** – the message body

As stated here, `on_before_message` is invoked "**so that implementing listeners can pre-process the content**." If you don't need to pre-process the content of the message (i.e. the headers or the body) then you can ignore this method.

As the name indicates `on_before_message` is invoked immediately before `on_message`.

Comment: It appears that both of those questions have been deleted now. Can you shed any light on that?

Comment: Both [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60642211/connection-is-disconnected-in-stomp-protocol-to-activemq) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60642538/1602853) (mentioned in previous comments) have been deleted. Clicking on either results in a "Page not found" message from Stack Overflow.